# Develop picture album using codeigniter, query to select images?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I am developing a web application using codeigniter.In there i am making a part to show images like in facebook as this screenshot.
[image: image1]

For that i have created two database table.One to keep album names with user id.One for to keep images names with album id.Here i am providing the screenshot of two table.
[image: image1]

[image: image2]

I have lot of albums in the album table for one user.now i have entered only one data to this table just for test.how can i select only one image from one album to create album view like in Facebook wish i have shown in the top of this question as screenshot.I create a query like this in the model to select image.

```
$username=$this->session->userdata('username');
         $this->db->select('id');
         $this->db->where('email',$username);
         $query=$this->db->get('user');
         foreach ($query->result() as $row)
         {
             $user_id= $row->id;

         }



         $this->db->select('*');
         $this->db->where('album_images.user_id',$user_id);
         $this->db->from('album_images');
         $this->db->join('album', 'album.id = album_images.album_id');

         $query = $this->db->get();
         return $query->result();
```

How can improve this code to select only one image from each album and pass all the details of that image such as image id, album_id,album_name,image_name to the view?

Comment: what is wrong with your current code?

Comment: Add limit to it using $this->db->limit(1);

Comment: I have lot of albums in album table.At this time only i have enterd only one data to table just for check.So I want to get one image from all that albums at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$this->db->select('uai.album_id, ua.album_name, uai.id as image_id, uai.image_name');
$this->db->from('user as u');
$this->db->join('album as ua', 'ua.user_id = u.id', 'left');
$this->db->join('album_images as uai', 'uai.user_id = u.id AND uai.album_id = ua.id', 'left');
$this->db->where('u.email',$this->session->userdata('username'));
$this->db->group_by('uai.user_id, uai.album_id');
$this->db->order_by('ua.album_name ASC');
$query = $this->db->get();
return ($query->num_rows() > 0) ? $query->result() : false;
```

*Output* will like following

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [album_id] => 1
            [album_name] => Apple
            [image_id] => 1
            [image_name] => Apple1.jpg
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [album_id] => 2
            [album_name] => Orange
            [image_id] => 3
            [image_name] => Orange1.jpg
        )

)
```

`image_name` will return one image from `album_images` table

```
ex. `[image_name] => Apple1.jpg` from (Apple1.jpg,Apple2.jpg,Apple3.jpg ..etc)
```